# gsap animation - import only one svg or multiple svgs

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, gsap

I would like to do "complex" animation with gsap and svgs.
but I don't know what is the best approach to this.
it is better to create and to import an unique svg with all the elements or maybe it is better 4 different svgs?

I have 4 different characters: a tree, a lamp, a desk and a man.
basically my animation is move the objects on the x, and  appearing and to disappearing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of the animation are part of one complex animation, you can use one single SVG for this.

To control the DOM of the SVG via CSS and JavaScript you need to add the SVG directly inline into your HTML page. Not embed via img tag or object tag or similar.

```
<body>
  <h1>My SVG Animation</h1>

  <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <circle class="animation-element-01" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
    <rect class="animation-element-01" x="150" y="20" width="150" height="150"/>
    <!-- etc -->
  </svg>

</body>
```

Another advantage of this method is, that there is no additional html requests.

Plus the whole animation can be made responsive via the viewBox.